# Powershell Script to log into Multiple machines

Tags: networking, powershell, multiple-monitors

I just go promoted to lead technician for my department. I'm in charge of over 400+ computers at any given time. Recently, I have found it to be troublesome when I need to update a program on each machine. I'm pretty new at scripting, but I was wondering if there is a way to log into all the machines via powershell? Going around machine by machine to log in is too time consuming and tiring.

Answer (score 1):

You should use group policies or logon scripts instead of walking around the office. Attend to a class like [Managing Windows Environments with Group Policy](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/course.aspx?id=50255b) or pick up some basic books about Windows network administration.